# Copying mysql database from mysql community server into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Using the command line, I'm able to see a database with several tables but trying to access that database from phpmyadmin and it's not there. Is there a way to bring that particular database into phpmyadmin?

Comment: Check that you are connecting to the same host and with the same credentials in both phpMyAdmin and the command line.

Comment: @SashaPachev This was it! Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.